# Задача на Stepik

Tags: python

Помогите с задачей, не могу понять что не устраивает сайт.
собственно сама задача:
Из передачи “Здоровье” Аня узнала, что рекомендуется спать хотя бы AA часов в сутки, но пересыпать тоже вредно и не стоит спать более BB часов. Сейчас Аня спит HH часов в сутки. Если режим сна Ани удовлетворяет рекомендациям передачи “Здоровье”, выведите “Это нормально”. Если Аня спит менее AA часов, выведите “Недосып”, если же более BB часов, то выведите “Пересып”.

Получаемое число AA всегда меньше либо равно BB.

На вход программе в три строки подаются переменные в следующем порядке: AA, BB, HH.

Обратите внимание на регистр символов: вывод должен в точности соответствовать описанному в задании, т. е. если программа должна вывести "Пересып", выводы программы "пересып", "ПЕРЕСЫП", "ПеРеСыП" и другие не будут считаться верными.

Это первое не самое тривиальное задание на условное выражение. В случаях, когда разбить исполнение программы на несколько направлений, стоит внимательно обдумать все условия, которые нужно использовать. Особое внимание стоит уделить строгости используемых условных операторов: различайте \lt< и \le≤; \gt> и \ge≥. Для того, чтобы понимать, какой из них стоит использовать, внимательно прочитайте условие задания.

мое решение:

```
A = int(input())
B = int(input())
H = int(input())

if H < A:
    print("Недосып")
elif H < B and H > A:
    print("Это нормально")
elif H > B:
    print("Пересып")
```

Answer (score 1):

нужно было в условии H < B and H > A сделать H <= B and H >= A
Вопрос закрыт

Comment: Это условие можно короче записать: `A <= H <= B`

Answer (score 0):

```
A = int(input())
B = int(input())
H = int(input())

if H < A:
    print("Недосып")
elif H <= B and H >= A:
    print("Это нормально")
elif H > B:
    print("Пересып")
```

Если вы получили 0 из 1 балла, нажмите кнопку "Решить снова".

Comment: По сути это дубликат предыдущего самоответа